# Differential Equation change of variable

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule

I'm investigating how you get from this:

$$ z\frac{d^2y}{dz^2}+(1-a)\frac{dy}{dz}+a^2z^{2a-1}y=0 $$

to this:

$$ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+y=0 $$

with a change of variable:

$$ z=x^{1/a}, (x\ge0) $$

I'm not quite 'getting' the substitution in the derivative...

In a normal situation where we have $ \frac{dy}{dx} $ and a function $ y(x) $, we basically perform $ \frac{d}{dx}y(x) $ to see how $ y $ changes with respect to $ x $.

Now, with the variable substitution are we now saying that $ \frac{dy}{dz} $ is changed to $ \frac{d}{dz}y(z) = \frac{d}{dx}y(x^{1/a}) $.

This leaves me with a derivative that can be solved using the Chain Rule?

So, $$ \frac{d}{dx}y(x^{1/a})  = \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{x^{\frac{1}{a}-1}}{a}$$

I would then just proceed to take the second derivative and substitute $ \frac{dy}{dx} $ , $ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} $ and $ y $ into the equation original equation above.

Is my understanding correct on this please?  Thankyou.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note, that by the chain rule, we have 
$$ \frac{dy}{dz} = \frac{dy}{dx} \cdot \frac{dx}{dz} $$
and, taking another derivative, by product and chain rules, 
$$ \frac{d^2y}{dz^2} = \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} \cdot \left(\frac{dx}{dz}\right)^2
  + \frac{dy}{dx} \cdot \frac{d^2 x}{dz^2} $$
As $x = z^a$, we have 
$$ \frac{dx}{dz} = az^{a-1}, \quad \frac{d^2 x}{dz^2} = a(a-1)z^{a-2} $$
that is 
\begin{align*}
 \frac{dy}{dz} &= \frac{dy}{dx} \cdot az^{a-1}\\
 \frac{d^2y}{dz^2} &= a^2z^{2(a-1)} \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} +
                  a(a-1)z^{a-2} \frac{dy}{dx}\\
\end{align*}
Giving
\begin{align*}
  z\frac{d^2y}{dz^2} + (1-a)\frac{dy}{dz} + a^2z^{2a-1}y
  &= a^2z^{2a-1}\frac{dy^2}{dx^2} + a(a-1)z^{a-1}\frac{dy}{dx}
  - a(a-1)z^{a-1}\frac{dy}{dx} + a^2z^{2a-1}y\\
   &= a^2z^{2a-1}\left(\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + y\right)  
\end{align*}

Comment: Thankyou.  Where you have $ x = z^a $ and $ \frac{dx}{dz} = az^{a-1} $, is it feasible to write $ x(z) = z^a $ and therefore $ \frac{d}{dz}x(z) = az^{a-1} $ ?

Answer (score 0):

For change of independent variable as per wikipedia article on change of variables 
make NEW variable a function of old variable and other way for dependent variable. Then it falls out reasonably easily.